# Реально ли использовать Magento для интернет магазина в России?

Tags: magento, ecommerce

Возникла задача сделать интернет магазин для рускоязычной аудитории. Я думаю использовать Magento, но сомневаюсь насчет интеграции с русскими платежными системами и 1С подобными программами. Гуру, поделитесь опытом внедрения и использования Magento в России.

Так же знаю есть в Magento проблема с поиском. То есть встроенный поиск слабоват, для англ версии приходится использовать платное расширение. Как обстоят дела с русской версией?

Comment: есть всё, не сильно много, но есть. Комьюнити не слишком толстое, но многое решаемо. Руками пилить все-равно придётся.

Answer (score 1):

В странах пост СНГ Мадженто развивается постепенно, набирает обороты так сказать.

По вопросам:

1. Сразу скажу что лучше использовать чистую систему не сборку как например "Российская сборка" т.к. были прецеденты, но это на любителя.
2. С платежными системами есть несколько реализаций, есть и бесплатные(например [liqpay](https://github.com/liqpay/plugin-magento) для Украины) но список не очень большой.
3. Для поиска, особенно если сайт хотя бы среднего уровня и выше то желательно использовать сторонние модули, очень советуют поиск от Mirasvit.

Ну а в общем для интеграции с платежками, учетами  и т.д., нужно будет устанавливать сторонние модули чаще всего которые платные + думаю дорабатывать под сам сайт т.к. это часто бывает.

Описал немного в кратце, что знал, буду если хоть чуток помог).

Answer (score 0):

Крупные и известные магазины, работающие на Magento в России: http://magento-forum.ru/topic/4642/#russia
Магазины, работающие на Российской сборке Magento: http://magento-forum.ru/topic/2633